# How To Get Pydantic To Discriminate On A Field Within List[Union[TypeA, TypeB]]?

Tags: pydantic

I am trying to use Pydantic to validate a POST request payload for a Rest API. A list of applicants can contain a primary and optional other applicant. So far, I have written the following Pydantic models listed below, to try and reflect this. The Rest API json payload is using a boolean field `isPrimary` to discriminate between a primary and other applicant.

```py
from datetime import date
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator
from typing import List, Literal, Optional, Union


class PrimaryApplicant(BaseModel):
    isPrimary: Literal[True]
    dateOfBirth: Optional[date]


class OtherApplicant(BaseModel):
    isPrimary: Literal[False]
    dateOfBirth: date
    relationshipStatus: Literal["family", "friend", "other", "partner"]


class Application(BaseModel):
    applicants: List[Union[PrimaryApplicant, OtherApplicant]]

    @validator("applicants")
    def validate(
        cls,
        v: List[Union[PrimaryApplicant, OtherApplicant]]
    ) -> List[Union[PrimaryApplicant, OtherApplicant]]:

        list_count = len(v)
        primary_count = len(
            list(
                filter(lambda item: item.isPrimary, v)
            )
        )
        secondary_count = list_count - primary_count

        if primary_count > 1:
            raise ValueError("Only one primary applicant required")

        if secondary_count > 1:
            raise ValueError("Only one secondary applicant allowed")

        return v


def main() -> None:
    data_dict = {
        "applicants": [
            {
                "isPrimary": True
            },
            {
                "isPrimary": False,
                "dateOfBirth": date(1990, 1, 15),
                "relationshipStatus": "family"
            },
        ]
    }

    _ = Application(**data_dict)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

With the example json payload listed above, when I try to remove some of the required mandatory fields from the `OtherApplicant` payload a `ValidationError` is correctly raised. For example, if I try to remove relationshipStatus or dateOfBirth field an error is raised. However, the `isPrimary` field is also reported by Pydantic to be invalid. Pydantic believes that this the *isPrimary* field should be True??? Example Pydantic validation output is listed below.

Why is Pydantic expecting that the isPrimary field should be True for an `OtherApplicant` list item in the json payload? Is it somehow associating the payload with `PrimaryApplicant` because of the use of `Union`? If so, how do I get Pydantic to use the `isPrimary` field to distinguish between primary and other applicants in the list payload?

## Missing relationshipStatus field in list payload for OtherApplicant

```sh
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 2 validation errors for Application
applicants -> 1 -> isPrimary
  unexpected value; permitted: True (type=value_error.const; given=False; permitted=(True,))
applicants -> 1 -> dateOfBirth
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

## Missing dateOfBirth field in list payload for OtherApplicant

```sh
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 2 validation errors for Application
applicants -> 1 -> isPrimary
  unexpected value; permitted: True (type=value_error.const; given=False; permitted=(True,))
applicants -> 1 -> relationshipStatus
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Found the answer via also asking on [Pydantic GitHub Repository](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/discussions/3754)

Pydantic 1.9 introduces the notion of [discriminatory union](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#discriminated-unions-aka-tagged-unions).

After upgrading to Pydantic 1.9 and adding:

```py
Applicant = Annotated[
    Union[PrimaryApplicant, OtherApplicant],
    Field(discriminator="isPrimary")]
```

It is now possible to have `applicants: List[Applicant]` field in my `Application` model. The `isPrimary` field is marked as being used to distinguish between a primary and other applicant.

The full code listing is therefore:

```py
from datetime import date
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, validator
from typing import List, Literal, Optional, Union
from typing_extensions import Annotated


class PrimaryApplicant(BaseModel):
    isPrimary: Literal[True]
    dateOfBirth: Optional[date]


class OtherApplicant(BaseModel):
    isPrimary: Literal[False]
    dateOfBirth: date
    relationshipStatus: Literal["family", "friend", "other", "partner"]


Applicant = Annotated[
    Union[PrimaryApplicant, OtherApplicant],
    Field(discriminator="isPrimary")]


class Application(BaseModel):
    applicants: List[Applicant]

    @validator("applicants")
    def validate(cls, v: List[Applicant]) -> List[Applicant]:

        list_count = len(v)
        primary_count = len(
            list(
                filter(lambda item: item.isPrimary, v)
            )
        )
        secondary_count = list_count - primary_count

        if primary_count > 1:
            raise ValueError("Only one primary applicant required")

        if secondary_count > 1:
            raise ValueError("Only one secondary applicant allowed")

        return v


def main() -> None:
    data_dict = {
        "applicants": [
            {
                "isPrimary": True
            },
            {
                "isPrimary": False,
                "relationshipStatus": "family"
            },
        ]
    }

    _ = Application(**data_dict)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: In the `OtherApplicant`, I believe that you need to change the `dateOfBirth` field type to `Optional[date]`, otherwise Pydantic 1.9.0 will throw an exception:
`pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for Application
applicants -> 1 -> OtherApplicant -> dateOfBirth
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Life saver!